# Relative paths for portable notebooks in mathematica

Tags: windows, file, wolfram-mathematica, relative-path

I Cannot find how to use relative paths in mathematica.  My directory structure is simple.

```
Import["G:\\Research\\Acc and Vel Runs\\5-24\\Mathematica\\Data\\250 \
Acc.xls"][[1]] // TableForm
```

That Demonstrates the Absolute path by using the insert path from the menus.  I want this notebook to be portable.  I want to give someone the "Mathematica" directory and I want them to be able to run the code.  I don't want the paths to break because It will be run on a different machine.  Basically I just want to use a relative path starting at the Mathematica level shown above.

Comment: There is now a [dedicated StackExchange site for Mathematica questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), which you might want to consider using for future questions.

Comment: `SetDirectory[$NotebookDirectory]`?

Comment: @Verbeia Can you answer this question with an official answer but changing your answer to: SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]] and then the relative path Import["Data\\250 Acc.xls"][[1]] // TableForm....I will then accept your answer

Comment: In addition to NotebookDirectory[], I would also recommend using FileNameJoin[] to avoid Windows/Unix path separator issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Mathematica you can get the current directory using `Directory[]` and you can set it to something else using `SetDirectory[]`.  You can go back to the last location using `ReserDirectory[]` or check all previous locations using `DirectoryStack[]`.

This is described in the documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NamingAndFindingFiles.html).

You can set the current directory to the directory where the notebook is using

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

For `NotebookDirectory` to work, you must be using the Front End and the notebook must be saved.

You can always use path relative to the current directory (`Directory[]`), for example `Import["data/somedata.txt"]`.

Regarding directory separators: `/` will always works, on all of Windows/Linux/Mac.  When you are typing a relative path name, it's much more convenient to just use `/` for portability than `FileNameJoin`.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this.

```
SetDirectory[
  FileNameJoin[{$InitialDirectory, "dir1", "dir2"}]];
Quiet[Close["Log.txt"]];
logStream = Quiet[OpenWrite["xmlAreaTagsLog.txt"]];
xmlDoc = Import["XmlData.xml"];
```

Using $InitialDirectory gets you the .nb directory and using FileNameJoin allows you to have relative access.